# how to automatically UPDATE Android app from playstore

Tags: android

I have an app installed(created by me) on my android phone. How will I code the functionality to automatically update from Playstore, without notifying the user(since I have trusted the old app instalation).

Comment: Check this...i dont thinku can update automatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474040/update-application-programmatically-from-google-store-while-autoupdate-is-off-in

Comment: U hav to notify user befre update

Comment: Android probably wont allow app to do that without permission.

Comment: when user tapped auto update turn off manually in playstpre

Comment: *play store ...Turning the auot update on is the only option

Comment: You can't update your app automatic (force your users to update). With permission to install apps Android won't let you silently update apps, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission. You might get this to work if you request root permission on rooted devices.

Answer (score 3):

You can update your Android device's apps individually or allow them to be updated automatically:

1. Open the Google Play Store app Play Store.
2. Tap Menu Menu and then Settings.
3. Tap Auto-update apps.

Answer (score 0):

Set up automatic updates

To set up automatic updates for all apps on your mobile device:

> Open the Google Play Store app Play Store.
>
> Tap Manu - > **Settings**.
>
> Tap **Auto-update apps**.
>
> Select an **option**:
>
> **Auto update apps at any time**: Updates apps at any time, using either
>   Wi-Fi or mobile data.
>
> **Auto-update apps over Wi-Fi only**: Updates only when you are connected to Wi-Fi.

**Note**: If an account on your device has a sign-in error, apps may not update automatically.

You can google it also same processor written everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

@ratheesh

Inside your `SplashActivity` only if you want to force update

```
 final String appPackageName = getPackageName();
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The method for turning on and off automatic app update on Android devices has changed several times over the years.  For example, see [How to Disable Automatic App Updates in Android](https://www.howtogeek.com/202297/how-to-disable-automatic-app-updates-in-android/).  And for example, [current Google Play Help advice](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113412?hl=en) is not applicable for users running the latest Android and Google Play Store software versions.

I am running Android Version 10 with One UI Core 2.5 and Google Play Store Version 25.5.22-21 on a recently-acquired Galaxy A12 phone.

On my phone, after opening the Google Play Store app, I click on my round Google profile icon (in the orange square in the image below) in the upper right corner of the Play Store app window,

[image]

click on Settings (in the red oval in the image below),

[image]

and select 'Auto-update apps' in the Settings window.

An implication is that changing the auto-update setting is now going to affect all Android devices being managed via that Google profile.

I hope this helps others trudging along in my footsteps.